# R dplyr select not removing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm a new user of R and have a very basic question. I'm trying to delete columns using the dplyr select function. It appears to run correctly but then when the data is viewed using head the deleted column still appears, and also a count is still able to be run on this column. I've run this on a very simple test dataset, the outputs are below. Please advise on how to permanently delete the columns from the data. Thanks

```
> library(dplyr)
> setwd("C:/")
> mydata <- read_csv("test.csv")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  Age = col_double(),
  Gender = col_character(),
  `Smoking Status` = col_character()
)
> head(mydata)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
    Age Gender `Smoking Status`
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>           
1    18 M      Smoker          
2    25 F      Non-smoker      
3    40 M      Ex-smoker       
4    53 F      Non-smoker      
> select(mydata,-Age)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Gender `Smoking Status`
  <chr>  <chr>           
1 M      Smoker          
2 F      Non-smoker      
3 M      Ex-smoker       
4 F      Non-smoker      
> head(mydata)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
    Age Gender `Smoking Status`
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>           
1    18 M      Smoker          
2    25 F      Non-smoker      
3    40 M      Ex-smoker       
4    53 F      Non-smoker      
> mydata %>% 
+ count(Age)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    Age     n
  <dbl> <int>
1    18     1
2    25     1
3    40     1
4    53     1
```

Comment: You haven't assigned anything. `dplyr` functions (and many functions in R) don't make changes in place. If you want to make `mydata` = `select(mydata, -Age)`, you have to assign it with `<-` or `=`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please keep in mind that posts need to be edited properly. This is especially important for the code. Take a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question. The reason the column is not being deleted is because you are not assigning the data to a variable.

```
 df <- data.frame(age = 10:20,
             sex = c('M','M','F','F','M','F','F','M','F','F','M'),
             smoker = c('N','N','Y','N','N','Y','N','N','Y','Y','N'))
 df_1 <- select(df,-age)

 head(df_1)
  sex smoker
1   M      N
2   M      N
3   F      Y
4   F      N
5   M      N
6   F      Y
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted the first 4 rows (head) of your data and turned it into a reproducible answer which anyone can then copy and run easily. This helps us understand your problem which in turn helps you get your answer faster.

```
# Dataframe based on head of your table
mydata <- data.frame(Age = c(18,25,40,53),
                     Gender = c("M","F","M","F"),
                     Smoking_Status = c("Smoker","Non_smoker","Ex-smoker","Non-smoker"))

> mydata
  Age Gender Smoking_Status
1  18      M         Smoker
2  25      F     Non_smoker
3  40      M      Ex-smoker
4  53      F     Non-smoker
```

Essentially you are creating a new data frame once you have transformed your dataframe in any way, and this new data frame needs to be saved into a variable. This can be done by using either `=` or `<-`.

I prefer using `<-` as it helps differentiate assigning a variable.

If you have no need for your original dataframe, you can simply overwrite it by assinging the new data frame with the same name.

```
mydata <- select(mydata, -Age)
```

To preserve your original data frame, you can create a new variable and store this data frame inside. Now, `mydata` is still the same as above but `mydata2` has no Age column.

```
mydata2 <- select(mydata, -Age)

> mydata2
  Gender Smoking_Status
1      M         Smoker
2      F     Non_smoker
3      M      Ex-smoker
4      F     Non-smoker
```